# Hibernate invalid configuration mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, ms-access

Good Morning to everyone!
I´m trying to use Hibernate to read an MSAccess database in Java using Eclipse, but it gives me a MappingException

here is  my hibernateaccess.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <session-factory>

        <property name='connection.driver_class'>net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver</property>
        <property name='connection.username'></property>
        <property name='connection.password'></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name='connection.pool_size'>1000</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">600000</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name='dialect'>dialect.MSAccessDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name='show_sql'>true</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->

        <mapping class="TransporteAccess.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the TransporteAccess.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Transporte" table="Transportes">
        <property name="transporte" column="TRANSPORTES" type="string"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Which I´m doing wrong???
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mandatory to have Primary Key in Hibernate, [refer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) 
Add Primary key as well,

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

apart from this the hibernateaccess.xml contains some irrelevant tags

Update top lines in hibernateaccess.xml with

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
```

& change

```
<mapping class="TransporteAccess.hbm.xml" />
```

to

```
<mapping resource="TransporteAccess.hbm.xml" />
```

Comment: But the table hasn´t primary key( iit is an old database maden by no informatic people)

Comment: Just add default primary key with default behaviour, as hibernate won't work without primary key

Comment: Added and not working, I think that the error comes from Hibernateaccess.cfg.xml, due to if i comment  <mapping class="TransporteAccess.hbm.xml" /> the error still hapens

Comment: Initially it was throwing MappingException as mentioned in issue!!

Comment: This is the exception INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernateaccess.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Comment: Man you have messed your configuration file with mapping files, correct it, I have updated the answer

Comment: adding the new lines gives me a different error: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernateaccess.cfg.xml
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128053/discussion-between-niranjan-kumar-and-vlopez).